multiple single select using slim select
I am attempting to clone a SlimSelect instance. However, after cloning the select element and trying to initialize the SlimSelect on the cloned element, I encounter a problem. The value of the cloned select element remains the same as the original one, and the dropdown menu fails to open. Could you assist me in identifying what might be missing or incorrect in my code?


const btn = document.getElementById("add-button");
const formClone = document.querySelector(".clone");
const parentForm = document.querySelector(".wrappers");
    
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const newId = makeid(10);
      const clone = formClone.cloneNode(true);
      const arr = clone.querySelector("[name='ArrLists']").id;
      arr += newId;
      parentForm.appendChild(clone);
    
      const deleteForm = document.createElement("button");
      deleteForm.innerText = "X";
      deleteForm.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger", "btn-sm");
      clone.appendChild(deleteForm);
      
      new SlimSelect({
  select: arr
});
    
      deleteForm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
      });
    });
    
new SlimSelect({
  select: '#single'
});
    
    function makeid(length) {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < length) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/slim-select@latest/dist/slimselect.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button id="add-button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Add Form</button>
<div class="wrappers">
  <div class="row clone mb-2">
    <div class="col px-0">
      <select id="single" name="ArrLists">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="value 1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value 2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="value 3">Value 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/slim-select@latest/dist/slimselect.min.js"></script>




const id = makeid(10); - so you went through the trouble of generating a random ID - and then you're not using it for anything, anywhere ...?

But even with that fixed, there is also a data-id property on the select, and the following div that provides the flyout for the options - and those are having the same values across all your clones. I think you should really rather clone a "naked" select field, rather than one that you already applied SlimSelect to.

@CBroe sorry, I have just updated my snippet

Cloning the element that you already applied SlimSelect to, appears to be leading to trouble. Clone an unmodified select element instead.
I added the hidden attribute to your "original" of the row to be cloned here, so that the "naked" select doesn't show up. You might want to place it outside of your actual form, so that this row doesn't submit a value as well. (Or you could use a template element for this part to begin with.)
And then I simply trigger a click on your "Add Form" button, to get the first initial SlimSelect set up.
Note that your makeid can create IDs that start with a digit - which leads to trouble when using that value in an ID selector, #1foo is simply an invalid selector, it would need additional escaping. I removed the digits from your string of possible characters - fell free to add them again, but make sure the first character is always a letter then.


const btn = document.getElementById("add-button");
const formClone = document.querySelector(".clone");
const parentForm = document.querySelector(".wrappers");

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newId = makeid(10);
  const clone = formClone.cloneNode(true);
  clone.removeAttribute('hidden');
  clone.querySelector("[name='ArrLists']").id = newId;
  parentForm.appendChild(clone);

  const deleteForm = document.createElement("button");
  deleteForm.innerText = "X";
  deleteForm.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger", "btn-sm");
  clone.appendChild(deleteForm);

  new SlimSelect({
    select: '#'+newId
  });

  deleteForm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  });
});

btn.click();

function makeid(length) {
  let result = '';
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  let counter = 0;
  while (counter < length) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    counter += 1;
  }
  return result;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/slim-select@latest/dist/slimselect.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button id="add-button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Add Form</button>
<div class="wrappers">
  <div class="row clone mb-2" hidden>
    <div class="col px-0">
      <select id="single" name="ArrLists">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="value 1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value 2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="value 3">Value 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/slim-select@latest/dist/slimselect.min.js"></script>




So the options to make this happen are using a hidden attribute or using a template element?

The main part is cloning of an unmodified select element, so that the additional properties that applying SlimSelect adds, don't interfere. How you hide the original select (which you presumably don't want the user to see), is secondary. Could use display:none as well; you just need to make the cloned row visible again. And if you leave this inside your form, that original select field will also cause an entry in the form submission data set - which you likely won't want either. If this was done using a template instead, that could stay inside the form.

I just need to wrap my SlimSelect in a template tag and clone from that? This way, I won't need to use a hidden attribute or display:none, and the select element won't be included when I submit the data?

Your whole <div class="row clone mb-2">...</div> should be wrapped into the template, since you want to clone the whole row each time, and not just the select field.

yeah, I mean like that

Thanks for your help. If I have any questions in the future, I'll come back and ask you.
